# Delete IP Address and Subfolder from All Links Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, replace, each

I'm trying to write a jQuery script that will replace all absolute URLs in a page with relative URLs by removing an IP address and folder name from the front, e.g.:  should become

```
jQuery('a').each(function() {
    var oldURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var newURL = oldURL.replace('http://123.456.789/folder.com/', '/');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', newURL);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well.... what's happening for you? [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/nnuc45yk/)